# object module needs to implement 'My_Property' for interface

Tags: наследование, vba

Изучаю наследование в VBA. Вроде всё по примерам, но не компилируется, выдаёт ошибку

> object module needs to implement 'Kind_Name' for interface 'TFileKind'

базовый класс TFileKind

```
Public Function Validate() As Boolean
    Validate = False
End Function

Public Property Get Kind_Name() As String
    Kind_Name = ""
End Property

Public Property Get Fields_Count() As Integer
    Fields_Count = -1
End Property
```

наследник TFileTSN

```
Implements TFileKind

Public Function TFileKind_Validate() As Boolean
  TFileKind_Validate = False
End Function


Private Property Get TFileKind_Kind_Name() As String
  Kind_Name = "TSN"
End Property

Private Property Get TFileKind_Fields_Count() As Integer
  Fields_Count = 4
End Property
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что нельзя в VBA использовать символ `_` в идентификаторах свободно. 
Если убрать из имён свойств в предке этот символ, и провести соответствующее изменение в наследнике, то код будет компилироваться без ошибок.